# Passing arguments to build.gradle

Tags: docker, spring-boot, gradle, environment-variables

I am building a springboot application using gradle.

The build eventually outputs a docker container and I want my build.gradle to support multiple environments.

I am using `gradlew build docker` to build and the docker section of my build.gradle is :

```
docker {
  dependsOn build
  name "app-production"
  files bootJar.archivePath, 'application.yml'
  buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "${bootJar.archiveName}"])
}
```

I successfully passed arguments to the dockerfile but now I also want to pass arguments to the build.gradle file. Is it possible using `gradlew build docker`?

I need something like this : `gradlew build docker --env=qa` and then :

```
docker {
  dependsOn build
  name "app-${env}"
  files bootJar.archivePath, 'application.yml'
  buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "${bootJar.archiveName}"])
}
```

NOTE: `${bootJar.archiveName}` is a local variable in my build.gradle, not an environment variable

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Project Properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:project_properties) to pass values to your *build script* from command line, as follows:

```
gradlew build docker -Penv=qa
```

Then in your build script you can access this property :

```
docker { 
    name "app-${env}"
    // ....
}
```